# how to write use case diagram and description for tow user

Tags: use-case

how to write use case diagram and description for tow user A and B do the same use case but user B can do things in use case not available to A

Comment: Write use case for both user and take reference for A user from B this is only for use case description, if you want to create UML diagram take inheritance for A from B @elezabith

Answer (score 1):

Write use case for both user and take reference for user A from B, this is only for use case description, if you want to create UML diagram take inheritance for A from B.